# Routes with Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, ionic4

Hi I did a Page with Ionic 4 base on Angular, so I used the routing of Angular with guards to manage the access.

I get the information with  a APIRest made on Expres JS (I did that).

Then I published the site on internet, but I have some rutes on Ionic 4 and if the user refresh the page with that urls, Express JS try to search, but the rute doesn´t exist on Express then I get a Error 404

I thing the solution is redirect when I get a 404 error, but I don´t sure if is a good practice that, I want use the best option

```
const express = require('express'),
    routes= require('./routes/router')
```

Routes

```
router
    .get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(`${reqPath}/views/index.html`) // Redirect to Ionic App
    })
    .post('/login', Controller.login)
    .post('/CreateUser', Controller.CreateUser)
    .post('/SendAlert', Controller.Alert)
    .post('/Articles',Controller.Articles)
```

Ionic App app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './Login/login/login.module#LoginPageModule', canActivate: [LoginGuardService] },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home/home.module#HomePageModule', canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { path: 'add-user', loadChildren: './User/add-user/add-user.module#AddUserPageModule', canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
  { path: 'user/:user', loadChildren: './User/user/user.module#UserPageModule', canActivate: [UserGuardService] },
  { path: 'add-article/:idarticle', loadChildren: './User/add-article/add-article.module#AddArticlePageModule', canActivate: [UserGuardService] },
  { path: 'add-device/:iddevice', loadChildren: './Device/add-device/add-device.module#AddDevicePageModule', canActivate: [DeviceGuardService] },
  { path: 'simulations/:device', loadChildren: './Device/simulations/simulations.module#SimulationsPageModule', canActivate: [DeviceGuardService] },
  { path: 'profile', loadChildren: './Profile/profile/profile.module#ProfilePageModule' },
];
```

I have access to the login, and access fine, but if I nav to page http://mypage.com/user/FirstUser all it's ok, until reflesh the page, I get 404 Error because that rute doesn´t exist on Expres JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how router in Ionic does. But if it did not have a router in express js, you can this one.

```
router
    .get('user/:user', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(`response_file_to_redirect_Ionic`) // Redirect to Ionic App
    })
```

Comment: But if I do that, I need to make a rule for each case and how ionic knows how it works, only want to delegate the route.